# Gravityform return 0 after submit

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Can someone help me sort out this gravity form issue? Gravity form doesnt submit, it returns 0 after clicking the submit. Is this ajax? or Gravity form?

This is the PHP code.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action_callback', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    $form_shortcode_display_on_right = get_field('form_shortcode_display_on_right', 'options');
    if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
        $gf_how = $_REQUEST['gf_how'];
        if ($gf_how == 0) {
            gravity_form ($form_shortcode_display_on_right, true, true, false, false, false, false, true );
        } else {
            echo 'Form loaded on footer';
        }
    }
    wp_die(); 
}
```

This is the ajax

```
var gf_how = 0;
$('body').on('click load', '.close-button, .open-form', function(){
        var dd = $('.dd').text();
        
        if ($('.floating-form').hasClass('show')) {
            gf_how = 0;            
        } else {
            gf_how = 1;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,            
            data: {
              action: "my_action_callback",
              gf_how: gf_how, 
            },           
            success: function (data) {
                $('.gf_show').empty();  
                $('.gf_show').html(data);
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
              alert("There is an error with AJAX!");
            },
        });       
});
```

Comment: set `gf_how` to `0` if your ajax returns `Form loaded on footer`, from there you will start debugging to know where the issue is. but if you are getting `0` now that shows your ajax is working but not working correctly, because `wp_die` was supposed to kill the script

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. This is what the it goes when clicking the submit button.. Please see screenshot https://prnt.sc/o-AGqq8XnZgt
The gravityform sends fine if I wasnt using ajax to display GF form

Comment: You are visiting the ajax link directly from the screenshot, and with that, you will always get `0` because that is the default value for WP ajax. Although not the right to do AJAX, if you want that your function to run add `?action=my_action_callback` to the end of that URL

Comment: Thank you @WisdomIghofose that works.. Can I ask one more thing? How to stay on my current domain? Coz it was still redirected to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action_callback but the message sent out successfully.

Comment: We can't see what exact elements you are adding your event handlers to there, but it sounds as if you are still letting the form submit normally, because you did not prevent the default action of clicking the submit button.

Comment: @JoelAlemaida What you did with visiting the URL is not AJAX if you need to perform an ajax request then you should be visiting the page where you have the button with the classes `.close-button` or `.open-form`